# LINQ User input column WHERE clause

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

is there any way i can change the `WHERE` clause dynamically on user input in my query?

The user will choose which column to filter and what id's or what ever is to be filtered in that column.

here is my code so far

```
 public List<AssetDetailsToDisplay> FilterGridview2(String Samplequery)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Data.AMSEntities model = new Data.AMSEntities())
            {
                var list = from asset in model.Assets
                           join employee in model.Employees on asset.owner_id equals employee.employee_id into assetlist
                           where(Samplequery) // this is where the user inputed query should be executed

                           select new AssetDetailsToDisplay
                           {
                               id = asset.AssetSubClassRel.id,
                               asset_id = asset.asset_id,
                               short_description = asset.short_description,
                               inventory_id = asset.inventory_id,
                               class_id = asset.AssetClassRel.table_value,
                               subclass_id = asset.AssetSubClassRel.table_value,
                               ast_status_id = asset.AssetStatusRel.table_value,
                               location_id = asset.AssetLocationRel.table_value,
                               subclass_key = asset.AssetSubClassRel.table_key

                           };
                return list.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

example of query that the user will be inputting

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSample" CssClass="form-control" Style="width: 120px;" runat="server" Text="owner_id <> ''"/>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Business.Users users = new Business.Users();
     string samplequery = txtSample.Text
     users.FilterGridview2(samplequery);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyFilter 
{
   public int? ById { get; set; }
   public string ByName { get; set; }
   /// etc...
}

IQuerayble<Asset> GetAssets(MyFilter filter) 
{
    IQueryable<Asset> query = model.Assets; 
    if (filter.ById.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(a => a.Id == filter.ById.Value);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(filter.ByName))
        query = query.Where(a => a.Id == filter.ByName);

    query = query.Select(... // your select code here);
    return query;
}
```

If you want to simply pass the column name and value, then you'll have to look into reflection and the C# `Expression` builder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to search in any fields?

Maybe you should try this IQueryable extension. It can search in any string property

```
public static IQueryable<T> Relevant<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry, string keyword, bool AllKeywordMustExist = true, char keywordSeparator = ' ')
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "relev");

        var objectType = typeof(T);
        var stringProperties = objectType.GetProperties().Where(m => m.PropertyType == typeof(string));

        var keywords = keyword.Split(keywordSeparator)
            .Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))
            .Select(m => m.ToLower())
            .Distinct();

        Expression completeExpression = Expression.Constant(AllKeywordMustExist);
        foreach (var keywordExpression in keywords.Select(m => Expression.Constant(m)))
        {
            Expression keywordCompleteExpression = Expression.Constant(false);
            foreach (var prop in stringProperties)
            {
                var containExpression = CreatePropertyContainExpression(parameter, prop, keywordExpression);
                var notNullExpression = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, prop.Name), Expression.Constant(null));
                var notNullContaintExpression = Expression.Condition(notNullExpression, containExpression, Expression.Constant(false));

                keywordCompleteExpression = Expression.Or(keywordCompleteExpression, notNullContaintExpression);
            }

            if (AllKeywordMustExist)
            {
                completeExpression = Expression.And(completeExpression, keywordCompleteExpression);
            }
            else
            {
                completeExpression = Expression.Or(completeExpression, keywordCompleteExpression);
            }
        }

        return qry.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(completeExpression, parameter));
    }

 private static Expression CreatePropertyContainExpression(Expression instance, PropertyInfo instanceProperty, Expression keyword)
    {
        var containMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1);
        var toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "ToLower" && m.GetParameters().Length == 0);

        var propParam = Expression.PropertyOrField(instance, instanceProperty.Name);
        var tolowerExp = Expression.Call(propParam, toLowerMethod);
        var containExpression = Expression.Call(tolowerExp, containMethod, keyword);

        return containExpression;
    }
```

To use it just call

```
data.Relevant("rob");
```

Here's a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/4iXf9M

Comment: Lito lapid ftw! good to see a fellow Filipino here, thanks alot!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?:

```
 var list = from asset in model.Assets
                       join employee in model.Employees on asset.owner_id equals employee.employee_id into assetlist
                       where asset.subclass_id == subclass_id
```

Comment: im afraid not, the user will have his freedom to choose what column to filter